# Django one to many get all underlying records

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'am creating a django application with a database including the following tables:[image]

I created the models as following:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    text = models.CharField(db_column='Text', max_length=4000)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Group'


class Filters(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    text = models.CharField(db_column='Text', max_length=4000)
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 db_column='GroupId')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Filters'
```

The goal is to call an endpoint and return a list with all Groups and underlying Filters. Is it possible to achieve this? If possible, I want it in a Serializer class.

I know I can get the group of a filter record, but is this also possible the otherway around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    text = models.CharField(db_column='Text', max_length=4000)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Group'


class Filters(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    text = models.CharField(db_column='Text', max_length=4000)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 db_column='GroupId', related_name='filters') # not group_id
```

This just says, Filters has .group but a group has .filters (related_name), If you didn't specify a `related_name`, It will be `model_qs` by default, so it should be `filters_qs`.

Some additional notes

- Class names should be **singular**
- Django creates plural names by adding 's', In your case it will create filterss and you'll have to specify a `verbose_name_plural` (more useless code)
- You don't need to specify db data, column names or whatever unless you're re-creating a backend that already exists or something that needs that.
- It's group and not group_id, We all know that in SQL it's the group_id, however, This is python and you have access to the whole group instance then you `instance.id` or `instance.pk` to get it.

Comment: Thanks! The additional notes were very usefull, I am still in the process of learning Django. But how can I return a list of groups with underlying filters as json from the endpoint?

Comment: see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/)

Comment: I got it working with [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Comment: Yes this should get the same, I actually forgot that you're using drf

Comment: that's why I sticked with django, But serializers in drf are much more powerful and maintainable, Specially with nested models