# Django problem with foreginKey in templates

Tags: django

I am started learning Django and I have question. I have code like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Worker(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 32, blank=False, null=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 32, blank=False, null=False)

class Computer(models.Model):
    TYPE = {
        (0, 'PC'),
        (1, 'Laptop'),
    }
    workerId = models.ForeignKey(Worker, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    prod = models.CharField(max_length = 32, blank=False, null=False)
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=TYPE)
```

What I should do in views and templates if I want to do list with workers and theirs computers? One computer can be for one user or for no one but one worker can have a few computers.

My template for this look like:

```
{% block site %}
    {% for work in worker %}
        <p>{{ work.id }} {{ work.fullname }} 
            {{ work.lastname }}</p><br>
            {% if comp.workerId == work.id%}
                {{ comp }}
            {% else %}
                <p>Empty</p>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for c in comp %}
        <p>{{ c }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I always have "Empty". Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this with [**`for-empty`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) in template:

```
{% for work in worker %}
    <p>{{ work.id }} {{ work.fullname }} 
        {{ work.lastname }}</p><br>
        {% for comp in work.computer_set.all %}
            {{ comp }}
        {% empty %}
            <p>Empty</p>
        {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually explained this before in 2 questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876212/how-to-display-img-file-in-django-template/60877112#60877112) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481929/django-one-to-many-get-all-underlying-records/61482119#61482119).

Basically, a `ForiegnKey` object is a key because it's unique for the class owning it, This means your computer has only one worker, BE SURE TO CALL IT WORKER, NOT WORKERID as this is OOP and when you access `mycomputer.worker`, you have a `Worker` object which has `.id` and `.pk` so it makes no sense to call it `workerId`.

Each worker now has a `.computer_qs` which you can change like this

```
workerId = models.ForeignKey(Worker,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             blank=True, null=True, related_name="computers")
```

don't forget to call it `worker`. now it's `.computers` instead of `.computer_qs`.

In your templates iterate `workerObj.computers.all` to access single computer objects and have fun with it!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped.